# Huge JSON lists without eating all the memory

Tags: python, celery

I have a queue endpoint (Celery) that consumes a batch of messages before working on them, then writes them all into **a temporary file** for another process(Spark clustering) to consume. Its basically a huge list of dicts, encoded in JSON.

```
[{'id':1,'content'=...},{'id':2,'content'=...},{'id':3,'content'=...}.....]
```

But we keep all messages in memory, then a `json.dumps` that also generates a big string in memory. So can I do better than storing it all in memory? Can I dump messages to the file as they arrive, so it does not consume too much memory?

Comment: You'd have to look at code which handles these messages and maybe get it to write to files immediately. I don't know how big these files are, but if they are sufficiently large enough maybe consider a sliding window mmap: https://pypi.python.org/pypi/smmap.

Answer (score 1):

Write your own JSON Encoder for efficient json encoding. Or just use [`json.dump`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/json.html#basic-usage) by passing in file pointer like object.

Also, don't read the whole json file into memory when consuming the data. Use `json.load` instead of `json.loads`, and use the standard [Python iterator interface](http://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#iterator-types)